# avalondock 3.3.0.0 mvvm LayoutAnchorable

Tags: wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I am trying to use mvvm for avalondock
I have the following property

```
Property Documents = New ObservableCollection(Of Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable)
```

in my ViewModel i have the following

```
    Dim RemindersView As New ViewReminders ' This is a simple user control 
    Dim NewItem As New Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable
    NewItem.Title = "My Reminders"
    NewItem.ContentId = "MYID123"
    NewItem.Content = RemindersView
    Documents.Add(NewItem)
```

XAML ( for simplicity i did not include the full xaml)

```
 <ad:DockingManager AnchorablesSource="{Binding Documents}">
```

When i run the application i can see the title of each document but i cannot see the user controls/Views

I only get the following :

[image]

If i use static the user control is shown correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figure it out :

1st. Create your ViewModels with what ever need to hold + create a simple property Title

e.g

```
    Public Class MyViewModel : Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Sub NF(ByVal PN As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PN))
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        Title = "This is My Title"
    End Sub

    Property RefreshCommand As New MyCommands(AddressOf RefreshCommand_)

    Private Sub RefreshCommand_()
        MySomeList =' Get your list from SQL/ MANUALLY OR WITH WHAT EVER IT IS THAT.
    End Sub

    Private _Title As String
    Property Title As String
        Get
            Return _Title
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Title = value
            NF("Title")
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _MySomeList As IEnumerable
    Property MySomeList As IEnumerable
        Get
            Return _MySomeList
        End Get
        Set(value As IEnumerable)
            _MySomeList = value
            NF("MySomeList")
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

2nd. Create your Views either as a UserControl or within your DockingManager Resources as a DataTemplates..(example XAML below)

The Observable Collection should be of type of your object that holds your **ViewModels** and **NOT** Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable

e.g

```
    Documents = New ObservableCollection(Of Object)
    Dim DocumentsVM As New UserDashBoard.DocumentsVM
    Documents.Add(DocumentsVM)
    Dim CustomerBalancesVM As New UserDashBoard.CustomerBalancesViewModel
    Documents.Add(CustomerBalancesVM)
    Dim TransactionsVM As New UserDashBoard.TransactionsVM
    Documents.Add(TransactionsVM)
    Documents.Add(New UserDashBoard.RecurringTransactionVM)
```

Then in DockingManagerResources you define your dataTemplates like

```
      <ad:DockingManager.Resources>              
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type profile:CustomerBalancesViewModel}">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="White"  HeadersVisibility="None" GridLinesVisibility="None" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn    Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="50"  Binding="{Binding Balance}" >
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ad:DockingManager.Resources>
```

Then run your sample /test and you will see your views ..

At least this should get you start up before changing other templates or styling the docking manager.